# Lock screen rotation on a Surface 3 - Windows 8.1 C# WPF

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, .net-4.5

I have an application that I developed in C# (Windows Forms). I am trying to force landscape view and lock the application so it will not rotate when the Surface rotates.

I have found ways to do this in 8.1 RT and on the Windows Phone but not Win 8.1 or 10.

I don't want to use the Windows settings and lock the Surface each time they run the app.

Comment: Not that is effects the screen location setting, but your title says WPF, and your question says Windows Forms.  Which are  you using?

Comment: Having tried to do the same thing with a WPF app, I can say there's no easy clean way to do it as far as I could tell after quite a lot of research